# Grabbing only HTML div from php file through jQuery GET

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP file which might contain lot of PHP tags, scripts and HTML.

I need to get only HTML div inside the php file. The file contain lot of `<?php >` tags. I want to ignore those tags and to get only HTML from the page using `jQuery.get()`.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Where is the code..??? Post it before geting downvoted

Comment: maybe this helps http://api.jquery.com/Types/#String

Comment: Is the PHP not executed, eliminating the PHP tags and leaving only the HTML? Are you sure this is a PHP *source* file you want to query?

Comment: I tried to ask in detail here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786927/loading-specific-html-styles-through-jquery-get, but no one answered, so i wonder whether this is possible or not. Only so i asked without any code just to find out whether its possible.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a .php file in your browser, the server executes the PHP files and only gives HTML (+javascipt +css) back. JavaScript is then executed *in* your browser and you won't have any `<?php ?>` tags inside. Therefore you can simply use [jQuery selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp).